# Update DB while changing values in table's cell

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, webix

Since I am quite new in web programming, can anyone suggest me what will be the best (from design and ease of implementing point of view) solution for implemeting below idea:

I am retrieving data from MySQL database and loading it to table. For that I am using Webix which did the trick.

- Then, I would like to be able to change data in each cell and once I
  click Enter, data to be updated in DB or saved till I click for e.g.
  Submit button.
- Another thing is kind of "Mass Update", for e.g. I want to change all
  cells in Column (for e.g. I want to set same date for all rows) of
  the table.

I think that first goal I can achieve with help of Webix like that:
[(edit each cell separately)](http://webix.com/demo/datatable/validation/), but even here I don't see how data transfers back to the server / DB / file, but as I understand it is changes only in the table itself.
Here is the source code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Datatable Validation</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../codebase/webix.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
        <script src="../../../codebase/webix.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../common/samples.css">
        <script src="../common/testdata.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='header_comment'>Cell validation</div>
        <div class='sample_comment'>Rank and Votes columns must contain positive numbers</div>
        <div id="testA"></div>
        <hr>
        <div id="testB" class='sample_comment'></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        function positiveNumber(value){ return value > 0; }

        webix.ready(function(){
            grid = webix.ui({
                container:"testA",
                view:"datatable",
                columns:[
                    { id:"rank",    header:"", css:"rank",  width:50,   editor:"text"},
                    { id:"title",   header:"Film title",    width:200,  editor:"text"},
                    { id:"year",    header:"Released" ,     width:80,   editor:"text"},
                    { id:"votes",   header:"Votes",         width:100,  editor:"text"}
                ],
                rules:{
                    "rank":positiveNumber,
                    "votes":positiveNumber
                },
                editable:true,
                autoheight:true,
                autowidth:true,

                data:small_wrong_film_set,
                ready:function(){
                    this.validate();
                }
            });     
        });

        </script>

        <input type="button" value="Add row" onclick="grid.add({ rank:-1 })">
    </body>
</html>
```

So I would really appreaciate if you could let me know the best or easier solution (I am not asking to write it for me, but will say thanks if you do so :) ), but if you can tell me widget or add-on or whatever what I can use to achieve these two goals.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: Other than that.. you should check out ajax, with which you can make asynchronous requests from the front end to the back end.

Comment: In short, take a look at http://docs.webix.com/helpers__ajax_operations.html and how to use it in http://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.text_onchange_event.html the idea is when you edit anything you call a server script which will mirror the change in the database. This is way too long a thing to explain in a place like this. I suggest you use the webix docs and maybe other tutorials.

Comment: Oh sorry, that is my mistake.. Should I delete topic somehow?